# Changing CSS class through jquery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'd like to change a CSS class property through jquery.  I have an example that isn't working.  When the button is clicked, it should change the label text to green.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

HTML:

```
<label class="somethingcustom">My Label</label><br>
<button onclick="javascript:changeColor();">click me</button>
```

CSS:

```
label.somethingcustom {color:red;}
.greenLabel label.somethingcustom {color:green;}
```

jquery:

```
function changeColor() {
    $('label.somethingcustom').parent().addClass('greenLabel');
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/bq4ruekj/1/

Comment: Your code is working [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ljpdh66/) just need to wrap your code in head

Comment: works fine when function is in scope  http://jsfiddle.net/bq4ruekj/4/ Look at errors thrown in console in your example

Comment: Why no one ever upvotes questions on stackoverflow?  Always downvote nowadays. sad.

Comment: WHy? because the code works fine when executed properly

Comment: Hence the question...duh!  Anyway, downvotes aren't allowed on this question so remove them.

Comment: but your only problem was in setting up an external tool incorrectly. The error thrown in console was easy to spot

Comment: ...and I'll take two downvotes for that solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `.parent()` use this code:

```
function changeColor() {
    $('label.somethingcustom').addClass('greenLabel');
}
```

and redefine your css like this:

```
label.somethingcustom.greenLabel {color:green;}
```

Comment: This changes the way it works, but doesn't solve the base problem. The base problem of the fiddle, as pointed by Satpal, is that the javascript should be wrapped in head. (See console error)

Comment: @vals: Ragnar's answer is spot on so go away with your downvote.